# AttributeError: instance has no attribute error in Linux only

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the `AttributeError: PortalTesting instance has no attribute 'reporting_screenshot'` error in Linux only. When I run this code on Windows, its working as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


class PortalTesting:

    def __init__(self):

        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.status = OrderedDict()
        self.screenshots_folder = ''
        self.new_folder_name = ''
        self.tday = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M')
        self.dt = date.today() - timedelta(2)
        self.start_date = self.dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

        # self.reporting_screenshot = ''
        # self.transcript = ''


    def login(self):

        try:
            URL = ''
            driver.get(URL)


    # ------------------- Transcript ------------------- #

    def transcript(self):
        try:
            tr_e1 = driver.find_element_by_id('Transcript_ID')
            hover1 = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(tr_e1)
            hover1.click().perform()
            ....
            ....

            self.transcript_screenshot = self.path + self.tday + "_Transcripts.png"
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file(self.transcript_screenshot)
            self.status['Transcript'] = ["Pass", self.transcript_screenshot]

        # THIS IS WHERE I GET ERROR
        except:
            self.status['Transcript'] = ["Fail", self.transcript_screenshot]

    # ------------------- Reporting ------------------- #

    def reporting(self):

        try:

            # Reports tab
            rpt_e1 = driver.find_element_by_id('report_menu_id')
            hover1 = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(rpt_e1)
            hover1.click().perform()

            .....
            .....
            WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'PortalChartContainer'))).click()
            self.reporting_screenshot = self.tday + "_Reports.png"
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file(self.path + self.reporting_screenshot)
            print("Reporting check complete.")
            self.status['Reporting'] = ["Pass", self.reporting_screenshot]

    # THIS IS WHERE I GET ERROR
        except:
            self.status['Reporting'] = ["Fail", self.reporting_screenshot]


pt = PortalTesting()

pt.login()
pt.reporting()
pt.transcript()
pt.admin()
pt.print_status()
```

What I am doing here is, login to URL. Run reports/ transcript. If success, add Pass and screenshot to `self.status` dictionary. If fails, add Fail and screenshot to `self.status` dictionary.

Above code works fine on Windows but, gives error when I copy paste same code on Linux.

If I add `self.transcript = ''` and `self.reporting_screenshot = ''` in `__init__`, I get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Traceback Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "DC1PortalTesting.py", line 477, in <module>
 pt.reporting()
 File "DC1PortalTesting.py", line 375, in reporting
 self.status['Reporting'] = ["Fail", self.reporting_screenshot]
 AttributeError: PortalTesting instance has no attribute 'reporting_screenshot'
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What's the exact error? (please copy the full traceback)

Comment: The first error is happening due the exception clause running before you set `reporting_screenshot` on `self`. The second error happens because you are overwriting the transcript function of the class with `self.transcript = ''`. No idea why the code is raising an exception in linux though.

Comment: @FabienP, `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DC1PortalTesting.py", line 477, in <module>
    pt.reporting()
  File "DC1PortalTesting.py", line 375, in reporting
    self.status['Reporting'] = ["Fail", self.reporting_screenshot]
AttributeError: PortalTesting instance has no attribute 'reporting_screenshot'
`

Answer (score 0):

@merlyn is right: the first error arise because of you `try/except` statement in the definition of `reporting()`. If any error pops up **before** `self.reporting_screenshot = self.tday + "_Reports.png"`, then the attribute does not exist, and the `except` clause will raise this error.

Two suggestions here:

1. `self.reporting_screenshot` should be create at first in the definition of `reporting()`, because all its components already exist at this point.

   ```
   def reporting(self):

       self.reporting_screenshot = self.tday + "_Reports.png"    

       try:

           # Reports tab
           rpt_e1 = driver.find_element_by_id('report_menu_id')
           hover1 = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(rpt_e1)
           hover1.click().perform()

           .....
           .....
           WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'PortalChartContainer'))).click()
           # Removed line here
           driver.get_screenshot_as_file(self.path + self.reporting_screenshot)
           print("Reporting check complete.")
           self.status['Reporting'] = ["Pass", self.reporting_screenshot]
   ...
   ```
2. Catch the error in your except statement, for debugging purpose.

   ```
   ...
   # THIS IS WHERE I GET ERROR
       except Exception as e:  # catches any exception
           # print(e)  # uncomment for debugging, or make it smarter with a switch
           self.status['Reporting'] = ["Fail", self.reporting_screenshot]
   ```

Regarding the other error: @merlyn also provided an explanation in his comment.

Regarding why your code fails on Linux: I assume it is working on Windows so you never tested the `except` clause there, right?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried as you suggested but, same error `('TRNSCRIPT ERROR====>', AttributeError("PortalTesting instance has no attribute 'transcript_screenshot'",))`

Comment: Can you try to uncomment the debug line to see what the original error is? But if you want more help you should provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so anyone can run through the error.

Comment: Yes, I followed the mcve and added in description. I won't be able to provide you URL as we are using it internally. What I am doing here is, `1.` Login to url `2.` Run reports, If reports are generated successfully, add Pass to `self.dictionary` and screenshot. If fails, add Fail to `self.dictionary` and screenshot. `3` Do the same for Transcript also. 
Once all done, create a html table with its status.`Reporting: Pass Link to screenshot ` Please let me know if you need anything else. I get the same error when uncomment debug line `AttributeError`

Comment: Unfortunately, if I can't run the code myself, it will be difficult to help you further...